# Retrieve data from a Quartz Job

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler and I have a job to process accounts:

```
public class MyJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
        List<String> accounts = (List<String>) ctx.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("accounts");
        for(String account : accounts) {
            // process account
        } 
    }

}
```

This works fine, but I have a button on the webpage and when I click it, I want to see the progress logged to my website. 
So on clicking the button an ajaxcall is done every second, but how can I return something from this job?

putting it on the jobDataMap didn't seem to work. Or maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

1. Store the progress somewhere externally (like database or synchronized map/coutner). `JobDataMap` is only updated when the job finishes. Your AJAX request can then query the global progress variable
2. Similar to 1.: send some event (JMS? maybe something more leightweight) and listen for that event somewhere else in your system.
3. Instead of one huge job processing all accounts schedule single job per account. Then you can monitor the progress of each individual job or see how many jobs finished.